# Create materializeView from consumer (functional programming model)

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to create a materialized view from a consumer, without really writing the logic for it? As my data in kafka topic can be materialized without any transformations

```
 1. Using KTable

@Bean
public Consumer<KTable<String, Pojo>> process() {
    return ktable -> <what should i do here>??;
}
```

I read in the docs that incoming KTable can be materialized directly doing
**spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.materializedAs: incoming-store**
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_state_store

```
 2. How about when using GlobalKTable ?

@Bean
public Consumer<GlobalTable<String, Pojo>> process() {
    return ktable -> <what can I do here>???;
}
```

**How about if I want MV from all partitions, is the code above a valid construct ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an empty consumer function as below.

```
@Bean
public Consumer<KTable<String, Pojo>> process() {
    return ktable -> {};
}
```

and then define the following config:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.materializedAs: my-store
```

Then the `my-store` becomes a materialized view of the underlying Kafka topic where `KTable` is consuming the data. You can use interactive queries against this materialized view.

The same is true for `GlobalKTable` as well.

For instance,

```
@Bean
public Consumer<GlobalKTable<String, Pojo>> globalProcess() {
    return gktable -> {};
}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.materializedAs: my-global-store
```

In languages like Kotlin, you can make the above functions as one-liners as below:

```
@Bean
fun storeBuilder() = Consumer<GlobalKTable<String, Pojo>> {}
```

Comment: Thanks Sobychacko ! You & Gary are always there to answer our queries.